# I have a default schema that is not dbo, why is the content in that schema not always consumed?

Tags: sql, security, schema

I work at a company, 8 months, that provides software to about 80 customers. I have been informed by one of the owners that I am now also the DBA. Until I came here my SQL Server experience has been mostly in the ETL and BI realm, I do not mind learning, so I am diving in. Our base content, stored procedures, function, view etc. are stored in the dbo schema. When we create custom content for a customer this is placed in the cus schema. We do not use the schema designation when consuming content. I have been told that our customers access the database with a single user, access security is handled in the application, and this user has the default schema of cus. Our customers are on a mix of sql server editions from 2008 R2 to 2014 mostly standard or express.

My problem is this. If I make a change for a customer to the base code, dbo schema, and save it in the cus schema then I need to also create an object for everything that calls that object up the call stack in the cus schema otherwise it will not be called. When I was first told this I was like ok that does not make sense but if you say so. My thought being that if content was in the default schema, cus, it would be executed as SQL Server would look there first before looking in the dbo schema.

I now have the opportunity to create all of this content and decided to test my belief in how I thought SQL Server worked and found that what I believe is true but only sometimes. I hope this is not one of those it depends situations and I just do not understand. Anyway I created 7 very simple functions in the dbo and cus schema like this

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Function_X](@Co int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
Select 'cus' as sche, 'Function_X' as fun ,@co as passed
union all 
Select * from Function_X_X(1)
)

They are identical except the ones in the dbo schema say dbo and the ones in the cus schema say cus. That way I know where they are called from. I actually tried to do this in extended events but could not find a way to do that, but I digress. The main function calls function_1, function_2, function_3 and function_4. Function_2 calls function_2_1 and that calls function_2_1_1 see below.

```
Function  
Function_1  
Function_2          
  Function_2_1              
     Function_2_1_1     
Function_3      
Function_4
```

By renaming various functions in the different schemas, so they would not be called, I was able to see which ones were executing in which schema. The results were not what I expected.

1   If the initial function is not in the cus schema then no functions in the cus schema are run.
2   Ignoring for the moment, functions 2_1 and 2_1_1, when the initial function is in the cus schema the four functions 1-4 will run from the cus schema if they exist otherwise they run from dbo so I will get a mix of cus and dbo schema depending on which functions exist.
3   If the function 2_1 is not found in cus then it runs in dbo as does function 2_1_1 even if it exists in the cus schema.

Example 2 executed as expected, however I was not expecting the results from example 1 or 3. I expected to see the cus function execute if it existed. In example 1 all the functions in the cus schema were ignored. In example 3 when function_2_1 was not found it ran the one in dbo as expected but then it also ran Function 2_1_1 from dbo.

Searching far and wide on the world wide web I could not see anything that touched on my question. I did stumble on a post that talked about the owner of the schema and the fact that they have a default schema. The owner dbo of the cus schema and the default schema of the login SA for the owner are both dbo. Thinking that might override the default schema, I created a new server login and database user with the default schema of cus and changed the owner of the cus schema. Alas no change in the result. I logged off the server and/or restarted the service when I did this. I did attempt this several times. I even created a new schema using the new login but got the same result.

Is there a way I can get SQL Server to use what is in the cus schema? Am I missing a setting or do I have to go and create all of that extra content?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to always fully qualify objects with the schema both when creating them and querying them. Relying on defaults is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, unfortunately, this is not a viable solution. Not all of our customers want, pay for or receive the same custom content. Most if not all custom content is unique to one customer. If we were to qualify everything we could end up with 80 versions of our application and that would be a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

The response from, Erland Sommarkskog, located here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73678fa7-0b9c-4780-ae16-197bd30aba3a/i-have-a-default-schema-that-is-not-dbo-why-is-the-content-in-that-schema-not-always-consumed?forum=sqlsecurity
answered my question as to this behavior. "once you are inside a module, it is the module that determines the default schema of unqualified objects, never the default schema of the current user."